# Scope mess with nested ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, scope

I've spent hours trying to understand why I'm fooled by this issue.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/ZJyTW/

The fiddle is just a simplified example of my issue.
The idea is to set some properties on the products, and the field values are filtered based on other fields. (eg. don't show 'Plane wing' options if type=car :-) )

```
<div class="productField" ng-repeat="field in product.fields | orderBy:order">{{field.name}} (hidden: {{field.disabledValue}}):
   <div class="productFieldContent" ng-hide="field.disabledValue">
        <select ng-model="product.values[field.name]" ng-options="design.text for design in field.values | filterValues:field:product.fields:product">
        </select>
        <button ng-click="$parent.field.disabledValue = !$parent.field.disabledValue">Toggle hide/show</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the Fiddle the third field is hidden until field1=value 1 and field2=Value 2:

```
if (arrayToReturn.length == 0) {
    fieldData.disabledValue = true;
} else {
    fieldData.disabledValue = false;
}
```

As you can see field 3 will display for Product 1 when other fields are set correct.
But the `{{field.disableValue}}` binding next to the field name does not show the correct value.

Here the weirdest part: The correct value (false) is shown next to field3 in product 2, even though field3 in product 2 stays hidden.

I pretty sure I got lost in the scope inheritance, and I'm pretty sure it's because of the two ngRepeats, but can someone please tell me what's going on? :-)

Thanks

Comment: The solution (thanks to @user1737909 ) is to change the line:

`$scope.products[i].fields = $scope.fields;`

to:

`$scope.products[i].fields = angular.copy($scope.fields);`

New working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hanspc/ZJyTW/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referencing the same fields - objects in javascript are passed by reference.

You have to "clone" `$scope.fields` each time you assign it to something, else it's gonna break :-). (ie http://jsfiddle.net/ZJyTW/3/ )

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it was that simple :-) You just saved my day!